# How do I change icon in the taskbar and title of Macroquad Rust framework on Windows?

Tags: windows, rust, icons

I recently got into macroquad framework for Rust and I managed to change the icon with winres, but only changes the .exe icon and I cannot figure out how to change it in the title and the taskbar.
Any ideas?
I use Windows 10.
I checked the documentation of the crate but no option for this is available.
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: macroquad uses miniquad, whose sapp-windows crate [doesn't set any window icon](https://github.com/not-fl3/miniquad/blob/f39f10ec81cd43246fb4431cb032de282354ff62/native/sapp-windows/src/lib.rs#L1227).  Perhaps make a feature request?